# how to input characters before a printf that should already be displayed?

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to create a program that looks like a resume using C++.  The problem is I can't figure out how to input over the printf display that should already be on the screen.  For example, I need to have this output:

```
Name: _________ _____________ ____ 
      Last Name First Name    MI
```

You see the Last Name, First Name and MI should already be displayed, but I should input my answer on the line before them.  I believe we should only use array, loops, functions(void) to create this and nothing more advanced than that.  Help!

Comment: You could try the carriage return character, but it's not nearly as reliable as a library that isn't part of standard C++.

Comment: If you are writing a console app, look into ncurses or search for "c++ console cursor positioning"

Comment: Are you on Linux or Windows?

Comment: is that UI a requirement? if so, you definitely need a console library.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the question seems to be asking for a solution without the use of "advanced" libraries, this is one possibility, based on ANSI escape sequences which can be found [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html).

It is meant as a starting example to show that this kind of thing *can* be done manually.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    // Clear screen.
    printf("\033[2J");
    printf("Name: _________ _____________ ____\n"
            "       Last Name First Name    MI\n");

    // Move cursor up two lines
    printf("\033[2A");
    // Move cursor forward six characters.
    printf("\033[6C");

    char lastName[20];
    char firstName[20];
    char MI[10];
    scanf("%s %s %s", lastName, firstName, MI);
    // Move the cursor down two lines
    printf("\033[2B");
    printf("Name: %s %s %s\n", firstName, lastName, MI);
}
```

Comment: Note that this is a Linux-specific answer, but the OP did not specify which OS.